# Log4j and Obfuscation with Proguard

Tags: maven, log4j, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my code via the MAven Proguard plugin, and it works almost perfectly : when running the obfuscated jar, I get warning and errors regarding log4j. The consequence is that I have no log at all (but the program runs correctly).

Here is my pom.xml Proguard part :

```
<plugin>
    <groupid>com.github.wvengen</groupid>
    <artifactid>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactid>
    <version>2.0.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
        <includedependency>true</includedependency>
        <options>
            <option>-keep public class my.package.MyMainClass { *; }</option>
            <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class org.apache.logging.log4j.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class org.apache.log4j.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keepattributes *Annotation*</option>
            <option>-keep class org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-adaptresourcefilenames</option>
            <option>-repackageclasses</option>
            <option>-overloadaggressively</option>
            <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainclass>MyMainClass</mainclass>
                <packagename>my.package</packagename>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupid>net.sf.proguard</groupid>
            <artifactid>proguard-base</artifactid>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And when running my obfuscated jar, I get errors and warnings like this :

```
main WARN Found a TypeConverter [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters$BigIntegerConverter@14c5515] for type [void] that already exists. (this warning for all Converters)

main ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class for plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout, element PatternLayout.

main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.ThresholdFilter for element ThresholdFilter.

main ERROR Null object returned for ThresholdFilter in Filters.

main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element Root.

main ERROR Null object returned for Logger in Loggers.

main ERROR Null object returned for Root in Loggers.

main WARN No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
```

any idea on why I cannot log ?
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: my program is just not logging anything by obfuscated classes. Unobfuscated classes, such as the main application entry point, are logging correctly though.

Comment: I fixed my issue by storing the obfuscated classes inside the Logger package name specified in my log4j2-spring.xml. That way all my a.b.c packages are still included in that Logger.